# Synchronization between ios devices

Tags: ios

First of all sorry for my English. I have searched but I didn't see nothing similar.

I have a problem and I don't know really how to make it.

I need to sync data between two or more iOS devices. This data could be a JSON or something similar.

Example:
Two iOS devices uses the same app, they are near each other(In the same place or room). There is a form and if I change a value in one of the devices the change should be shown in the other device automatically.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the Multipeer Connectivity Framework which is part of iOS 7.0.

[Apple's Multipeer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I think you are right, i'm implementing it and should work fine in my case.